# dpkg error processing package gdm3 (--configure)

Tags: error-handling

After I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 I have a black screen.
I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt full-upgrade -f 
dpkg error processing package gdm3 (--configure) subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10 . Errors weres encountered while processing: gdm3
```